# build/exe.win-amd64-3.6/scipy/misc/pilutil.py; import Image; moduleNotFoundError:No module named Image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, tk-toolkit

I am building EXE using python for Image processing.
I am using tkinter, cx_Freeze to build an application.

I am getting error

[image]

below is setup.py file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import matplotlib
from PIL import Image

import numpy.core._methods
import numpy.lib.format

import os.path


PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

base =None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"



executables=[
        Executable("application.py",base=base)
        ]
options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'include_files':[
            os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
            os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'),
            os.path.join(r'C:\Users\rahul\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy'),
        ], 
        'includes': ['numpy.core._methods', 'numpy.lib.format','numpy.matlib', 
                    'multiprocessing.process','matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg',
                    'matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg','PIL.Image',
                    ],
    },
}

setup(
    name = "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    options = options,
    version = "1.00",
    description ="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    executables = executables
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pip install Image
```

resolve my issue.